# Equivalent for "import type" using require in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to write something like the following code, except using `require` to be consistent with the rest of my imports:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't get what you need, can you explain it better? thank you

Comment: @InsalataCondita: If I'm using requires instead of imports, what should I write instead?

Answer (score 1):

`import type` indicates that you are only going to use a class as a type and not actually call methods of that class or construct instances of it within a module.

As far as I could find, there doesn't seem to be a direct equivalent using `require`, so the closest thing you can do is just a standard require:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
```

Instead, you can write the following using `require`.

```
const NextPage = require('next');
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare
type NextPage = InstanceType<typeof NextPage>;
```

Declaring the type and the class with the same name allows you to replicate the way the following would work:

```
import { NextPage } from 'next';
```

I included the following to hide the Eslint error:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare
```